# Developer story claims release dates are required, when they are not

Tags: discussion, bug, developer-story

I just noticed this bug and there are two ways of addressing it so I'm putting it out here.

[image]

The UI for Release Dates on Feature/Apps/Blogs/Videos says they are compulsory, however they are pretty much optional. This is surely a bug.

However, I am not sure whether Release Dates *should* be compulsory.

This situation is inconsistent, either this date is required or it isn't. Which is the correct behavior?

Comment: No dates please, this has already kept me from adding some ongoing projects I don't want marked as having dates.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's worth pointing out that this would make those apps float to the top, though, which might or might not be appropriate.

Comment: I currently have projects floating throughout the dev story willy nilly anyway. :-) My dev story was converted from a CV after all.

Comment: @Sklivvz Maybe we should be able to custom order items that don't have dates where we want?

Comment: @JamesBrierley I think that's on the roadmap already, but clearly this decision should not depend on that feature to be shipped first.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you should have them marked with "in about 6 to 8 months" though

Comment: Bug about the developer story directly from the developer story developer?  O wait you're on the core team...you're excused.  PS: Tell Joel I'm pissed about how trello was sold to atlassian bahumbug.

Answer (score 1):

The release date used to be required because we used it to place the item in reverse chronological order. After receiving some feedback, we decided to make this date optional to accommodate apps that do not have release dates, but we forgot to update the UI.

A fix has been made to appropriately show this field as optional. We are currently looking into improvements that will give you more control with the ordering of items as well as flexibility with dates.